# Adding multiple arguments to a target #selector in a UITableView

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, arguments, selector

I have a follow button in my table view cells when i click on it i follow a user by sending my user id and his user id to an api route.

```
var fbFriends = [People]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: FBFriendsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fbFriendsCell", for: indexPath) as! FBFriendsTableViewCell

    cell.friendFollowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

 @objc func followButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    user.followUser(token: Helper.shared.getAccessToken()!, userId: Helper.shared.retriveUserID()!, followeeId: fbFriendsData[indexPath.row].userId) { (status, code, err, msg, body) in

        //Do something with response
    }
}
```

What i need is to send the id of the user i will follow in the selector arguments so i can use it in the `followUser` function instead of the `indexPath.row` that is already out of the tableView closure. So what i need is something like this.

```
 @objc func followButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton, _ rowIndex: Int) {

    user.followUser(token: Helper.shared.getAccessToken()!, userId: Helper.shared.retriveUserID()!, followeeId: fbFriendsData[rowIndex].userId) { (status, code, err, msg, body) in

        //Do something with the response

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t pass parameters to your selector. Since you´re creating a button, why not just set the buttons tag to the id of the user and then in your `followButtonTapped`, just access it with `sender.tag`.

So:

```
var fbFriends = [People]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: FBFriendsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fbFriendsCell", for: indexPath) as! FBFriendsTableViewCell

    cell.friendFollowButton.tag = fbFriends[indexPath.row].userId
    cell.friendFollowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@objc func followButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    user.followUser(token: Helper.shared.getAccessToken()!, userId: Helper.shared.retriveUserID()!, followeeId: sender.tag) { (status, code, err, msg, body) in


        //Do something with response
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea its working i will just edit your code to the right answer thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that you must not use the row's indexPath as the button's tag if the table view supports rows being added, deleted, or moved.

Comment: Indeed, that’s why I wrote “the id of the user”.

Comment: Yes true. But the tableView doesn't support row adding or deleting it is just to display the users found on the database

Comment: @KeghamK., than you can use indexPath but I would still recommend the users id though.